# Any even $n> 10$ can be written as $n = pp'+p''$ for some primes $p,p',p''$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Conjecture:

> Any even integer $n>10$ can be written as $n=p\cdot p'+p''$, for some 
>   $p,p',p''\in\mathbb P$.

Verified for all $n<1,000,000$.

---

I first intended to post the weaker conjecture:
$\mathbb P\subset\Big(\mathbb P\cdot\mathbb P+\mathbb P+1\Big)\cup\{2,3,5,11\}$.

---

Comment: isn't that the same as saying every even  integer $n>12$ can be written as $pp'+p''$ ?

Comment: I would need some explanation of what the symbols mean.

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling:  Don't you mean every even integer n > 10?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Indeed, it's a very strange formulation - the Goldbach-likeness of the conjecture is much clearer in the statement in terms of even integers.

Comment: Why are you asking -- what's interesting about this variation of Goldbach?

Comment: I changed from odd to even.

Comment: You recently asked (then deleted) a question about differences of primes. There was a comment connecting it to the Goldbach Conjecture. That connection does not seem to be correct. However, there is an old conjecture, usually attributed to Maillet, that every even number can be expressed as a difference of primes. If Maillet's Conjecture holds, then so does yours. There is no reason to think yours is easier.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks! I suddenly realized it was a consequence of a known conjecture and deleted the question before reading comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't be suprised if this is extremely hard to prove and currently open.

Chen's theorem implies that every sufficiently large even number can be written as  $n=q\cdot q'+q''$, for some $q',q''\in\mathbb P$ and $q' \in\mathbb P \cup \{1\}$.

In 2015, an explicit bound was given for sufficiently large: $n>e^{e^{36}}$ is enough.

However, Chen's theorem is weaker since $q'$ might be $1$ instead of a prime number.

Comment: While testing BigZ at http://forthmath.blogspot.se I found that for intervalls of primes $I=[1,N]\cap\mathbb P, I\subset I*I+I+1$. When going to post that question it come to my mind that it might be extended to all odd numbers. Thereby the odd formulation before I changed.